# Filter rows above X percent of group in WebI report

Tags: business-objects, webi

We are running BusinessObjects 4.1 SP06 Patch 4. I need to build a Web Intelligence report that will only show the fees categorized by **Trans Code Desc** that are above 5% of the **Fee Schedule** to which they belong. I can find the percentage easily enough by adding a break on the **Fee Schedule**.

[image]

My **Transaction Percentage** is defined as follows...

```
=Percentage([Total Transaction Amount])
```

So I how do I add a filter to only show the rows with a Transaction Percentage > 0.05? I have attempted to make Boolean variable called **Transaction Percentage Above Threshhold**...

```
=If([Transaction Percentage] > 0.05; 1; 0)
```

I am pretty sure I know what is happening. I believe it is considering the Transaction Percentage for the entire report, not just within the **Fee Schedule** group.

I can highlight the rows with a **Transaction Percentage** greater than 0.05 using Conditional Formatting.

[image]

How do I apply a filter or at least create a Boolean variable so that it can be filtered in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that my problem was that my percentage was changing based on what was being filtered out. I did not want that. Basically, what I wanted was to show the percentage of each Tran Code Desc as compared to the total for each Fee Schedule even if some of the Tran Code Desc line items were filtered out for falling below the threshold.

I discovered another issue too. I had tried to simplify my situation for this question and left out a key detail in that there are more objects in my data set than I was showing. Therefore I was getting more than one line for some combinations of Fee Schedule and Trans Code Desc.

To get past these issues I created a few additional variables.

**Fee Schedule Trans Code Total** (eliminates multiple line items for some combinations of Fee Schedule and Trans Code Desc)

```
=Sum([Total Transaction Amount]) In ([Fee Schedule]; [Trans Code Desc])
```

**Fee Schedule Total** (prevents the total from changing with application of filters)

```
=NoFilter(Sum([Total Transaction Amount]) In ([Fee Schedule]))
```

**Transaction Percentage** (simple calculation using the previous two variables)

```
=[Fee Schedule Trans Code Total]/[Fee Schedule Total]
```

So here is the unfiltered result.

[image]

And here are the results filtered to only rows above the threshold. Note how the percentages or the remaining items have not changed after the application of the filter.

[image]

It seems like I am making this more complicated than it needs to be, but this works for me so I am going go with it for now.